# How to pull in tranasction level lines in a formula (NetSuite)

Tags: search, formula, netsuite

I am looking to create a transaction body field that uses a formula to source information from the transaction line on a sales order in NetSuite. This data would be the total weight of a shipment and could be multiple lines long.

Would it be possible to create a sum formula to generate this total? Something like the below (which does not work). Also how do you reference a transaction line item when your on the header level?

SUM({salesorder.quantity}*{salesorder.custbody9})
or maybe
case when {closed}='false'
then {salesorder.quantity}*{salesorder.custbody9})
else end

Answer (score 0):

You can use a field based on a saved search.

When you create a new transaction body field one of the options under "Validation and Defaulting" is 'Search'.

Check the help attached to that field for full details but basically:

Create the search that has a single summary column and give it a filter field for the transacton's internalid

select that search

When the form is loaded the search will be run and the value calculated.

Note that this sort of field only has a value when the transaction is loaded in the UI.
If you want value that you can include in saved searches you'd need to set the field using a script or workflow.